# Simplest way to store and return data on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, vaadin7

I have created an app to enable users to manually log data for their use of phytosanitary products in their fields.
I would like to store all of this data one the app engine.

I thought of storing it as entities on the google app datastore but then is there a way to gather all that data afterwards and make it downloadable as an XML file for example?

The only data that will be stored each time will be the following:
[image]

I am using Vaadin to handle the whole application

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you will need to write code to read data you want from Datastore and convert it to the form you need - XML or something else. Then you can trigger above functionality at a specific URL (click of a button) or as a scheduled job that emails you the XML or stores it in a Cloud storage bucket.